# Будет ли директива `listen 80;` принимать IPv6-соединения?

Tags: nginx

Будет ли директива `listen 80;` принимать IPv6-соединения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из [документации](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) это не совсем ясно.

практика показывает, что (в протестированной версии 1.10.3 из debian-овского пакета) ни одной из этих директив:

```
listen 80;
listen *:80;
listen *;
```

недостаточно, чтобы программа `nginx` принимала ipv6-соединения.

как минимум, надо указать аналог `*` («любой ipv4-адрес»):

```
listen [::];
```

или, с явным указанием порта:

```
listen [::]:80;
```

Comment: Дополнительный вопрос: директива `listen 80;` без параметра `ssl` принимает HTTPS соединения?

Comment: я же перечислил варианты, которых недостаточно. см. первый из них.

Comment: Нет, я спрашиваю не про IPv6, а про HTTPS.

Comment: прошу прощения, проглядел. нет, не будет: приём https — это ж целая история. помимо параметра `ssl` надо ещё и ключ указать и сертификат.

Comment: Да, разумеется с ключом и сертификатом. По-идее должен, ведь согласно документации параметр `ssl` носит запретительный характер. Ладно, не буду докучать, надо мне c letsencrypt разобраться и самому экспериментировать.